# Oracle PL/SQL: block parallel execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

I have a procedure like this.

```
create or replace
Procedure PROCEDURE_NAME
begin

Insert Instructions

Insert Instructions

Insert Instructions

Some Instructions

Some Instructions

Some Instructions


end;
```

The above shall be instruction blocks which can be executed parallel without having any sort of conflicts. How can I define in Oracle Procedure to execute them in parallel ?

I can make different procedures for them but looking for minimum modification in this procedure, I believe to call instruction parallel in SQL is possible.

Comment: Why all CAPS in question title?

Answer (score 5):

Executing multiple procedures in parallel can be done through DBMS_Scheduler chains. These allow a series of procedures to be executed based on success or failure of other procedures.

Oracle's SQL Developer has a graphical interface to help with it, although I've always coded them by hand myself.

There's a useful example in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#BAJHFHCD).

Comment: Again, I am not asking you how to run multiple procedures in parallel but how to run multiple statements within a procedure as parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should read [Oracle Docs about parallel execution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm)

But summarising, for a beginner:

You can specify a statement to be run in parallel(with a hint):

```
select /*+parallel(e 4)*/ *
from emp e;
```

You can set a table to be read in parallel:

```
ALTER TABLE emp PARALLEL 4;
--a select on it will run in parallel;
```

A function can be run in parallel if issued by a parallel query, adding PARALLEL_ENABLE after the returning clause when you define it.

A procedure can't be secified to be run in parallel, AFAIK(and it does not make much sense for me).

Comment: I need 2 statements to run in parallel. I think you should read it again now.

Comment: ouch, my answer is useless for your requirement, but I'll leave it here, maybe is useful for someone...

Comment: I think I understood it. PL/SQL does not have a native ability to run statements in parallel. Encapsulating the statements in a DBMS_Scheduler job is the most robust way of doing it.